# How to crop an image using ImageMagick from the command line?

Tags: shell, image-processing, command-line, cmd.exe, imagemagick

I am trying to crop a 640x640 image using ImageMagick on the command line.

I need to remove about 20 pixels from the bottom part of the image all the way from left to right. A long strip along the bottom.

I know about the [`shave`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave) command.

What would be the command to enter in the command line? I am using the Windows version of this software.

Answer (score 74):

Assuming that you always know the size of your image you can do it like this:

```
convert original.jpg -crop 640x620+0+0 cropped.jpg
```

With the `-crop` operator you specify the size of the cut out image and the offset from the upper left corner of the old image. In order to get rid of the 20px along the bottom, you have to choose a size of `640x620` and an offset of `0+0`

Comment: If you want to crop all the PNGs in your current directory, without keeping the original images: `mogrify -crop 1280x1024+0+0 *.png`. See also [this blog entry](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2014-11-15-how-to-crop-image-using-imagemagick.html) on `convert` and `mogrify`.

Comment: So, just to be clear, the syntax is `width x height + originX + originY`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, that looks correct to me with `imagemagick` 6.9.11-60

Answer (score 42):

Use **ImageMagick**'s `-chop` operator as follows to remove 20 rows of pixels from the bottom:

```
convert image.png -gravity South -chop 0x20 result.png
```

Change to `-gravity North` to chop top 20 rows.

---

Change to:

```
convert image.png -gravity East -chop 20x0 result.png
```

to crop from right side, note that the 20 pixels are now *before* the `x` separator.

Comment: Remove the zero (as in `1x20`) to actually remove anything

Comment: What is the purpose of the 0 for in the first place?

Comment: @kojow7 The 0 is not strictly required. I included it to demonstrate that the format is `WIDTHxHEIGHT` so that folks see the way to specify rows or columns which wouldn't have been clear if I had just said *"use -chop x20"*. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it took me a wile to get this right, so I thought let's post it here.

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q8\magick" convert -crop 100x100+800+600 fileIn.png fileOut.png
```

so one need both "magick","convert" without "-" and then the options with "-".
The history of this strange call is that convert used to be an executable (The only executable is magick). However since there was another windows system program with the same name "convert", it's now passed as an argument somehow. Moreover one needs to have the folder in path.

An easy batch to simplify the call could be:

```
crop fileIn.png fileOut.png 100,100,800,600
```

where the code would be

```
crop.bat

set fname1=%1
set fname2=%2
set x0=%3
set y0=%4
set w=%5
set h=%6
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q8\magick" convert -crop %w%x%h%+%x0%+%y0% %fname1% %fname2%
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect. Version 7 ImageMagick should almost **never** be used in the format `magick convert ...`. You should just use `magick INPUTIMAGE .... OPERATIONS ... OUTPUTIMAGE` unless you **specifically** want old Version 6 behaviour which is unwarranted in this example.

Comment: Thanks for letting the readers know. I was not aware. And also useful for myself, although the chance I will need magick again in the coming years is rather thin.

Answer (score 1):

- Crop centered in batches

  ```bash
  for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -gravity center -crop 98x98+0+0 +repage "$f" ; done
  ```
- Fulfil with `-extent` in a canvas `-background white`

  ```bash
  for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -gravity center -crop 98x98+0+0 +repage -extent 98x98 -background white "$f" ; done
  ```

Comment: `+repage` is required for `-crop` when the output format is webp